# Why doesn't my xsd file get copied in the build in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, build, xsd

My project has a folder with an xml file and an xsd file. When I build, the xml file is copied but not the xsd file. Why is that? The xsd is the one I actually need in my web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to properties of the .xsd file in the Properties window in Visual Studio and set `BuildAction` as `Content`.

Also there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747844/default-build-action-for-a-filetype) to set build action for .xsd files