# How can I change the check of Visual Studio if a project needs to be built

Tags: visual-studio, project, recompile

I' am creating a project template based on a .net core console app. It consists of typescript files which (when changed) need to trigger a recompilation of the project. This should be default on subsequent addition of certain ".ts" files.

When changes are made to .cs files, Visual studio knows when it needs to recompile based on own assumptions, not msbuild. This general behavior can be turned off by adding the following section to the csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>True</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I also learned from here ([How to avoid that Visual Studio incremental build does not run when files outside <Compile> and <EmbeddedResource> are changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026355/how-to-avoid-that-visual-studio-incremental-build-does-not-run-when-files-outsid/50040051#50040051)) that I can add

```
<UpToDateCheckInput Include="file.dat" />
```

to include a single file for that visual studio check. My question is:

How can I do this for all files of a certain type, let's say "*.ts"?

Also can I specify the default build action for a file to embedded resource or whatever once it is added to a project with my template?

Answer (score 0):

*How can I do this for all files of a certain type, let's say "*.ts"?* 
`<UpToDateCheckInput Include="**\*.dat" />` 
*Also can I specify the default build action for a file to embedded resource or whatever once it is added to a project with my template?*
[Default build action for a filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747844/default-build-action-for-a-filetype)